# "Failed to install gems via Bundler" when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, heroku

Background: I'm working through the book "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial" by Michael Hartl. I've gotten to the point where I'm setting up heroku. The text directs me to use sqlite3, but it seems that heroku no longer allows a sqlite3 backend. So, I'm trying to use postgres instead.

I'm working on a Mac, OS 10.6.8.

Problem: I try to do

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Then I get

```
Counting objects: 69, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), 26.69 KiB, done.
Total 69 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.rc.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --    binstubs bin/ --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * pg
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * sqlite3
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

With respect to "Run 'bundle install' elsewhere" -- what does elsewhere mean in this case? In another directory? I've tried that, to no avail. Also there's no Gemfile.lock file to add. In summary: I'm confused.

======

In response to hgmnz:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
( --- edited out ---)
Installing pg (0.14.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /sw/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
( -- edited out --- )


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adamshaw/.bundler/tmp/14373/gems/pg-0.14.0 for   inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adamshaw/.bundler/tmp/14373/gems/pg-0.14.0/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then

```
$ sudo gem install pg -v '0.14.0'
```

Then

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /sw/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
( --- edited out --- )

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.14.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, that seems to indicate that you've modified your `Gemfile` to include the `pg` gem, but haven't run `bundle install` (on your dev machine) to lock those gems down. Running `bundle install` will resolve all gem dependencies and generate a new `Gemfile.lock`. That's the file you should check into git and then attempt the deploy.

Run the following on your development machine:

```
bundle install
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Locking gems"
git push heroku # assumes default remote named heroku
```

Comment: Thank you. I eventually got this to work by installing postgres from source (after installing and subsequently uninstalling with fink, port and EnterpriseDB) and running

    sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the gem installer know where your PostgreSQL installation is located, because it needs to use some of those files when installing.

Check out [Error installing pg gem on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762131/error-installing-pg-gem-on-osx)