# Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I get the below error when I execute `bundle update`:

> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
>   be found here:
>
> /Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.

I don't know why I get this issue. And I execute the `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`:

> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
>
> /Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out

My Gemfile is this:

```
source 'https://gems.ruby-china.org'
gem 'rails', '5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma', '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier', '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
gem 'byebug', '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen', '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring', '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'

end
group :production do gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end
    # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

---

**Edit -1**

My OS is macOS Sierra

Comment: @Iceman I get `sudo: apt-get: command not found` if I use your recommend link/

Comment: Are you on a mac?

Comment: @Iceman yes I do.

Comment: Do you have PostgreSQL installed on your machine? How does the log in `/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log` look like?

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762131/error-installing-pg-gem-on-osx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem and this is what worked for me:

(Note: First make sure you've got XCode and homebrew installed)

1. `brew install postgresql`
2. `gem uninstall pg` - this might not return anything, that's ok.
3. Then in your app's directory, either `bundle install` or `gem install pg`

Answer (score 0):

This issue often comes up and mostly results in obsolete version of Postgres. 
Try

```
brew update 
brew install postgresql
bundle install
```

If you still need to use that version of Postgres you can specify the path to the 'pg_config':

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=<path to pg_config>
```